# Javascript commenting practice

Tags: javascript, comments

Recently, using comments in javascript I've run into a few questions about the commenting system. I wanted to comment on the name of a variable, so I put it right after declaring the name, on the same line, like this:

```
var wk /* (website key) */ = 1;
```

Now I think this is perfectly valid and works fine, right?

So a little while later, I wanted to comment out the whole block of code that line was on, like this:

```
/*

~ more code ~
var wk /* (website key) */ = 1;
~ more code ~

*/
```

But this doesn't work, because when the interior comment closes, it closes the whole comment. That seems kind of dumb to me. Is there any way to do nested comments in javascript?

Comment: @Alex ??? that doesn't make much sense. This has nothing to do with editors

Comment: Use meaningful variable names! We have [minimizers](https://developers.google.com/closure/) for a reason! `var websiteKey = 1;` And with modern day IDEs, they will do code completion for you!

Comment: Pretty simple that javascript comments don't nest.  So you can't put a `/* comment here */` inside of another comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't nest block comments, but you can do this:

```
var wk = 1; // website key
```

Or

```
// website key
var wk = 1;
```

It looks less awkward, and block comments are only really supposed to be used for... well, blocks. It's just better coding style in general.

Or, even better, make your code self-documenting and eliminate the need for a comment at all:

```
var websiteKey = 1;
```

Comment: I guess I just wanted to make it quicker to read, as the actual variable declaration is actually a lot longer than '1'

Comment: @eshellborn Then use the second style :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem recently where I had written some JavaScript for a friend on their wordpress blog. Anyway long story short they used the WYSIWYG editor, witch reformatted the page source.

so

```
<script type="test/javascript">
 $(function() {
     // this is a button click handler
     $('#button').click(function () {
         // did some stuff
     });
 })();
</script>
```

turned into

```
<script type="test/javascript">
     $(function() {// this is a button click handler $('#button').click(function() {
             // did some stuff }); })(); </script>
```

The point of the story is always be aware of your environment and the needs of your users, even when commenting

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var wk = 1; //Website Key - Additional Info Here
```

then if you need to comment the block, you can do

```
/*
  Comments and stuff go here...
  var wk = 1; //Website Key - Additional Info Here

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You never put single-line comment between the code. Reasons are that it is not readable enough and not being followed in the community as a best practice.
2. Putting away code via commenting it out is easily done with multi-line comment tags /* ... */ or single line ones //.

**PS**: For commenting I suggest to avoid doing magic stuff. I would not encourage nested commented at all! For having a consistent commenting style in Javascript try follow a pattern like JSDoc. In JSdoc, while commenting a block of code, you can do something like this:

```
/***
 *
 * @param param1
 */
var aFunction = function(param1) {
};
```

Readable, clean and no magic tric. It is great since it also embeds some sort of static type checking (I know JS is dynamically typed). Also check out this video from one of the guys behind integrating JSDoc into Intellij & Webstorm: [Dmitry Jemerov: Static types in JavaScript: what, how and why](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0r9HPRJUaFo)

Comment: updated my answer. was writing it before you saw it.

Comment: the OP wants to comment *out* a block of code, i.e., remove it.

Comment: What question did you just "answer"?!

Comment: It makes some sense now, some. And I don't like that you speak in behalf of the JS community.

Comment: I also deleted the JS community. I do not speak of it, nor anyone else. So If that makes sense now, you can stop voting down the answer all the time. That is my expectation!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid nested block comments. They are forbidden in the [ECMA Script specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4). If any interpreters allow this now, they may not in the future.

From Section 7.4,

> Comments can be either single or multi-line. Multi-line comments cannot nest.